# Is it possible for an iOS app to programmatically know when an APNS alert arrived on device?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

We have a notification centric application which receives notifications from a server via APNS. The server sends the alert at time T0. When the app is not in the foreground, iOS will alert the user using any one of the notification styles (including Alerts or Banner style in iOS 5) at time T1. The user then clicks the notification, the app launches and we use the details in the notification payload to fetch more details from the server etc at time T2.

It's easy to identify T0 (include it in notification payload) and T2 (available on device). Is there a way for the application to programmatically know T1 - the time at which the device received the notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are no APIs to get the time of which the message was actually delivered to the device.

The only case where you know T1 is when you receive the push notification while the application is in the foreground. Then iOS won't show any UI for it, it'll just call the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` method on your app delegate. And T1 will be identical to T2.